# Quick Action - Run code before a quick action is destroyed as a result of the X icon click

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-quickaction, lightning-modal

We are using an LWC as a quick action.

I believe that since the screen type is ScreenAction, Salesforce is creating a new modal window (inclusive of an X icon), and rendering our component's markup inside it.

The component displays a lighting-datatable of records, and if the user selects some records from that table and happens to click on the Cancel button (this is a custom lightning-button named Cancel in the modal footer), we have to show a lighting-confirm asking weather the user is sure to close the modal as he has unsaved changes. If he answers yes, we programatically close the modal by firing the CloseActionScreenEvent().

**The problem is that when the user clicks on the 'X' icon on the top-right of the modal, the modal closes automatically and the lightning-confirm does not show**

**How can we detect the clicking of the 'X' icon on the top-right?**

Answer (score 1):

You can't detect nor prevent the standard quick action modal's close button from being utilized. Instead, you'll want to consider using a [lightning-modal](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-modal/specification), and then *Enable the Component as a Screen Action* as described in [lightning-quick-action-panel](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-quick-action-panel/documentation). You can then use the `disable-close` property to prevent closing the modal under normal circumstances. However, this is an on/off feature, meaning the user will have to click cancel to close the modal. You can turn the attribute on/off based on if any selections have been made.